# Is the BalloonItemizedOverlay a library?

Tags: android, dictionary, balloon

I am a beginner android programming.I want to create a balloon on the map. I read mapViewBalloon-example on this link https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons but i don't know, is the BalloonItemizedOverlay a library?? Should i add it to the program or i should write BalloonItemizedOverlay class in the program?  I read this class but i could not understand most of the code of this class :(

Thanks for help.

Comment: please provide the code you have tried. so we can help you.

Comment: add it as a library. dl the whole project, import it in eclipse, make it a library, add it as a library to your project, and voila

Comment: I download the program(mapviewballoons_master) but i don't see the library.Where to find it? Do i import this library to my program? Should i understand the codes of BalloonItemizedOverlay or this like another libraries of android like android.content.Context?

Comment: Nobody is here? Please help me :( Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand answer of my question. Please help me my friends :)

Answer (score -2):

add a class extends  ItemizedOverlay (Not fully coded you should done everything.)

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {


//it gives abstract methods one of them is onTap (onTap will show dialog 
//when user tap overlay item).
  @Override
  protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setNegativeButton(dissmis, new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
  }

}
```

you i add alertDialog to handle balloon. And add some buttons if you want to dissmiss etc options.
Also you can add title and message to shown information(text).

Comment: i don't want create a dialogBuilder, i want to create a balloon like the balloon of google map. Thanks